# How to split InputStream into multiple BoundedInputStream without knowing total stream size?

Tags: java, inputstream, openstack-swift

I'm looking at [an open source Swift library](https://github.com/javaswift/joss) that is able to split an InputStream into multiple BoundedInputStream objects, given a total stream size (to know when to stop creating bounded input streams). I don't see why there should be no option to stop the BoundedInputStream creation automatically once the initial InputStream is closed.

The code looks something like this:

```
protected Long segmentationSize = 5368709120L;
protected Long currentSegment = 0L;
private InputStream inputStream; // supplied externally
private long inputStreamSize; // supplied externally

public void uploadSegmentedObjects() {
    InputStream segmentStream = getNextSegment();
    while (segmentStream != null) {
        // do something
    }
}

public InputStream getNextSegment() {
    if (done()) {
        return null;
    }
    InputStream segment = createSegment();
    currentSegment++;
    return segment;
}

protected boolean done() {
    return currentSegment * segmentationSize > inputStreamSize;
}

@Override
protected InputStream createSegment() throws IOException {
    BoundedInputStream stream = new BoundedInputStream(inputStream, segmentationSize);
    stream.setPropagateClose(false);
    return stream;
}
```

Essentially, I need to know how to rewrite the done() method such that it is not reliant on the inputStreamSize variable and instead returns null when the stream closes.

Comment: I think your understanding of what BoundedInputStream works and is for is flawed.

Comment: That may very well be the case. Today is my first day looking into this class. Is there anything in particular you think I may be missing?

Comment: The doc I read about this says that the purpose of BIS is to make sure that after content-length bytes are read that the stream is closed and the data delivered to the Java app. A closed InputStream is closed. You can't segment it into 5 regions closing after each one; it won't work. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BoundedInputStream.html

Comment: hmm I'm not sure which part of the link you are referring to. The code certainly works though. Maybe that part is related to the setPropagateClose() method?

Comment: It's right at the top

Comment: Perhaps you can quote the part that you are referring to? The first instance in which I see anything about closing the stream is "isPropagateClose()
Indicates whether the close() method should propagate to the underling InputStream." But that is not the same as automatically closing the initial InputStream when data is delivered to the app by the BoundedInputStream. Your comment also contradicts the simple fact that the code above does indeed work. (I've also made a minor edit to my post for clarity)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223847/discussion-between-azianese-and-controlaltdel).